# Launching Android Studio under Root every time

Tags: android, root

Is there anyway to permanently set some kind of rule to launch Android Studio as sudo, each and every time it is launched? I have been trying but I have not been able to set a "flag" to force it to launch under Sudo.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank You!

EDIT: I got it working. Both the answers worked, and I ran both of them to make sure I was not making any kind of mistake! Thank you!

Comment: You could try setting up the app short to point to a launcher script that actually uses the `sudo` command.

Comment: @ray i did try launching from terminal but it just pops up the installation dialogue. I will try your method, but I have very little knowledge on making launcher scripts. Would you have some kind of examples I could refer to?

Comment: Why do you want to run it as root?

Comment: i have to update it and there is a popup saying I can't update it unless it is in root. I followed the default installation guide and I installed it in /usr/locale

Comment: You shouldn't need to run all the time as root to upgrade

Comment: open a new question for that problem

Comment: the problem is that every time I sudo run it, the installation dialogue pops up, and not the "welcome" dialogue.  then it prompts me to install the WHOLE thing again.

Comment: @JacobVlijm when I use the first answer, it automatically asks for sudo password. Maybe because it has a sudo file linked to it? And the second one prompts me just as well. I ended up using the first answer for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I wouldn't recommend running the IDE as the `root` user, you could create (or modify) the `.desktop` file for the app and create a custom launcher script that uses `sudo`.

For example, I have `$HOME/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-studio.desktop` with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=2.1
Type=Application
Name=Android Studio
Icon=/home/ray/.android-studio/bin/studio.png
Exec="/home/ray/.android-studio/bin/studio.sh" %f
Comment=Develop with pleasure!
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-studio
```

You can modify the `Exec` line so that it points to a script of your own making, say, `Exec="/home/<yourname>/.studio-launcher.bash"`

This script could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo /home/ray/.android-studio/bin/studio.sh %f
```

With the `.desktop` file under the directory mentioned above, you should also get the app to show up in the launcher, as shown in the example below, which is of my laptop using `gnome-shell`.

[image: Android Studio App Launcher]

This is a better *long-term* solution because:

1. It's a one-time setup;
2. You don't need to run terminal commands every time (e.g. `alias`);
3. You don't need to *launch* it from the terminal every time (e.g. running the `astudio` command);
4. You don't need to modify code in `$HOME/.bashrc`, etc.

Comment: much simpler to do it my way

Comment: thank you so much! I will try it and update it here! Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: @MarkYisri Only in the short-term. Mine is a more long-term solution that doesn't require opening the terminal every single time, which the OP does not appear to want to do.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I cannot find the .home file for my studio. Do I have to create one or is there a specific location I have overlooked? If I do have to make one, can you tell me how to make one?

Comment: You said you installed AS under `/usr/locale/`, so the actual executable of Android Studio should be there somewhere. In my case, I chose to install it under a new directory called `.android-studio` within my home directory (i.e. `/home/ray/.android-studio`). You can use the GUI to create the directory, noting that file/dir names that begin with a `.` are meant to be "hidden", so you'll need to set your file manager (e.g. Nautilus) to show hidden files. Let me know if you still have questions.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `alias` command.

```
alias astudio=`sudo <ANDROID_STUDIO_EXECUTABLE>`
```

Comment: this seems simple enough. Do I make a script of some sort? Sorry for the dumb questions.

Comment: @guywiththeredflare If used "as is", you'll need to **1)** use the terminal to launch AS every time, and **2)** and run the full `alias` command shown every time *prior* to launching AS (commands last only for a particular terminal session), or **3)** edit your `$HOME/.bashrc` file to include the `alias` command as shown and then always do step 1 anyway. My solution is a one-time only thing, which I think is better long-term.

Comment: @guywiththeredflare you can just add it to the end of your `.bashrc` file

Comment: this works for me `alias astudio='sudo /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh'`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply and totally from GUI:

- to create a root owned shell file to launch it as root from GUI do:
  `sudo mousepad` create a .sh file, from instance save it in
  `/home/YOUR_USER/studio.sh`
- put in it this command: `gksudo android-studio` (if you don't have gksudo install package gksu to get it)
- from terminal change file permissions to execute it: `sudo chmod 775 /home/YOUR_USER/studio.sh`
- edit the menu entry to add the entry: settings -> menu edit
  (can change from your ubuntu version) add an entry for the shell
  script:  `/home/YOUR_USER/studio.sh`, you could use the original android studio icon for it

now you can launch the studio from the menu providing the superuser password